# How to check if a form contains a radio button or not?

Tags: jquery

I have a form where form element appears dynamically . I need to check if the form contains a radio button or not.

Comment: just delegate your radio button presence check code inside to document...Ex `$(document).on('event','selector',function(){ });`

Comment: to check it: `if($('form').find(':radio').length)`

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($('#myform').find(':radio').length) {
    // do something if found
    alert("Found "+$('#myform').find(':radio').length+" radio buttons.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well, you can do it like that:

```
if($(":radio", "#myform").length){
    // Bingo, I got it
    // do something
}
```